# Are not Angular animations tottally supported for (at least) Firefox if I add polyfills web-animations?

Tags: angular, cross-browser, polyfills, angular-animations

Anybody knows if Angular animations are not compatible for Firefox also when I add web-animation polyfills?

Im having this error related to animations of underlying elements.

```
ERROR DOMException [NotSupportedError: "Animation to or from an underlying value is not yet supported."
code: 9
nsresult: 0x806c0001
location: http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/animations/bundles/animations-browser.umd.js:2319]
```

If I add polyfills:

```
ERROR DOMException [NotSupportedError: "Animation to or from an underlying value is not yet supported."
code: 9
nsresult: 0x806c0001
location: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/web-animations/2.2.5/web-animations-next-lite.min.js:15]
```

So I guess sadly I can`t. But.

**Is there a way to polyfill this feature?**

I case of not. **Recommended do not use for production?** 
**Somebody knows when is intended to give full support for animations?**

Comment: It's supported and works in FF, but not all properties, Try to simplify the animation to the basics like opacity, width etc

Comment: It was a simple height change animation. What I thought it was because I was using more than 1 trigger that affected parent and child parts of the html template of the component. Anyways I have decided do not use it for now in production. Already CSS3 solves most scenarios and always we can play with ngClass to give more dynamism.

Answer (score 3):

Hi i have similar problem and here is exactly same issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14752 where i hope we make some progress.

BTW can you try one thing. I tried in Firefox setting in `about:config` this setting to true `dom.animations-api.core.enabled` and it started working.

Bad thing is that this is not solution. Problem is with auto styles.

Comment: BTW, @angular/animations are very well suited only for chrome browser.. I hope that the framework will be rewritten. Is not useful to have a very complex animations if that can work just in only one browser..

Comment: @AndreaScarafoni I implemented scale and opacity transitions for routing - works brilliant in Chrome, but with the polyfill in Edge/Firefox, it looks dreadful. I'm going to implement some basic translateX transition instead, see how it looks.